# Is there a boost equivalent of fstream that will throw on failure to open file?

Tags: c++, boost, fstream

Like the title says is there a boost way of acomplishing the same thing as with fstream, but with the diff that it will throw on failure, not set some flag inside stream?
I know I can manually check and return/throw, but I prefer not to polute my code with checks...

Comment: You can always configure the `ios_base::exceptions` mask so that `ios_base::failure` is thrown when `failbit` is turned on in the expection mask (which includes failure to open).

Comment: I know about that... if nobody comes up with a better solution Ill use that.

Comment: This is already a feature of the standard iostreams. What's missing?

Comment: nothing special, I just didnt want to have flag setting in the code or .is_open? Call me lazy or antiflaggot if you will :)

Comment: Checking for errors that you might be able to handle is _not_ pollution.  It's good programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thinking:

Using streams with exceptions and 'not to polute [...] code with checks' will 
produce useless diagnostic messages in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::fstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
    try {
        f.open("Not-Existing");
        int formatted_value;
        f >> formatted_value; // No matching input.
        // ... and imagine more
        if(f.eof()) { /* To ensure the entire stream is consumed, is not handled */ }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Failure [Something turned out wrong]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the exceptions are a good idea, but if you do want to go this route, you'll probably want to turn the exceptions back off before reading.  Otherwise, you'll get an exception for end of file as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze I am not saying 'exceptions are a good idea' in this context!